# Nested loop exercise in C - Could I write this better?

Tags: c, loops

The exercise is:

Use nested loops to produce the following pattern

```
A
BC
DEF
GHIJ
KLMNO
PQRSTU
```

What I wrote is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char ch[]="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    int x,y;
    int min,max,i;
    min=max=0;
    i=1;
    for(x=0;x<6;x++)
    {
        for(y=min;y<=max;y++){
            printf("%c",ch[y]);
        }
        min=max+1;
        max+=i+1;
        i++;
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Is there an easier, better approach that I can't think of?

Comment: Define "easier" and "better". This is very easy: `for(int i=0; i<1; i++) for(int i=0; i<1; i++)
  puts("A\nBC\nDEF\nGHIJ\nKLMNO\nPQRSTU");`

Comment: @Lundin Hahaha xD

Comment: Well, better could mean more readable, more portable, faster execution speed, less RAM use...

Comment: I meant solving the problem faster, and yes, to be more readable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an alternative:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
  {
  char c = 'A';

  for(int i = 5 ; i >= 0 ; --i)
    {
    for(int j = i ; j < 6 ; ++j)
      printf("%c", c++);

    printf("\n");
    }
  }
```

Rather than storing all the possible characters it prints each character individually, then increments the letter after printing. As expected, the output is:

```
A
BC
DEF
GHIJ
KLMNO
PQRSTU
```

Answer (score 2):

I did not test this code, but when you use a `char c = 'A';` variable and increment it, you avoid keeping different counter variables.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char c = 'A';
    int x;

    for(x = 0; x < 6; x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y <= x; y++){
            printf("%c", c++); //No need of the array
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char c = "A";` isn't valid c. And to be picky, incrementing a character isn't guaranteed to give the next letter in the alphabet, that's system-specific.

Comment: ITYM `char c = 'A';` ... but, anyway, this will not work on a computer that is not ASCII-based.

Comment: I did not know this, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @pmg — for 99.9% of C programmers, there is no problem with assuming contiguity of the alphabet.  I suspect I'm understating the percentage, too (it's closer to 100% than that).  EBCDIC does exist and is still used in a few select environments (IBM mainframes, primarily, or emulations thereof).  But most people don't work on those.

Answer (score 2):

The inner loop could iterate up to the value of the outer loop.
Use a counter to keep track of the character to print.
Use the count plus the outer value and the length of `ch` to limit the iterations of the outer loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ( void) {
    char ch[]="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    int count = 0;
    int len = strlen ( ch);

    for ( int outer = 0; outer + count < len; ++outer) {
        for ( int inner = 0; inner <= outer; ++inner) {
            printf ( "%c", ch[count]);
            ++count;
        }
        printf ( "\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could entirely get rid of that character array:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int x, y;
    int min, max, i;
    min = max = 0;
    i = 1;
    for(x = 0; x < 6; x++)
    {
        for(y = min; y <= max; y++)
            printf("%c",'A'+y); //No need of the array

        min = max + 1;
        max += i + 1;
        i++;
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: get rid of array ... unless you're on a EBCDIC (or Klingon) implementation :)

Comment: @pmg: but a Klingon implementation would NEVER print 'A', 'BC', 'DEF', etc as that clearly has no honor!

Answer (score 1):

My attempt

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    char *p = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    for (int row = 0; row < 6; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col <= row; col++) putchar(*p++);
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

https://ideone.com/I9kAC1

Comment: Confusing code layout — it looks like you're printing a newline iteratively.

Answer (score 0):

```
int a = 65;
int bound = 5;
for (int i = 0; i < bound ++i)
{   
    for (int j = 0; j <= i; ++j)
        printf("%c",(char)a++);
    printf("\n");
}
```

If by easy you mean less number of lines, try this. This uses ASCII values.

Comment: Use ASCII values ... unless using an EBCDIC (or Klingon) implementation :)

Comment: @pmg wow, really ?

Comment: @pmg I for one am strongly considering EBCDIC for my latest and greatest project. It's going to run on my 128 bit, one's complement computer with a byte size of 42 bits. I hope you are all considering code portability to this magnificent machine.

Comment: You mean by easy less number of lines. I dont think that user thinks the portabilitiy of this "exercise" code :) Keep going. The most portable and LTS nested loop program ever.

Comment: @Lundin Ooh, can I SSH into that computer to test my code?

Comment: @tango-1 To be serious, writing portable code is a very good thing, even if it's just an excercise. It puts a basis on what you can write once and run everywhere, as opposed to what you can only run in one place.

Comment: @S.S.Anne yes, absolutely.

Comment: @S.S.Anne There's a difference between considering portability between real world systems and portability to fictional or ancient systems. The former is a very good thing, the latter is a huge waste of everyone's time.

Comment: It would be clearer if you used `'A'`, though.